# Visual Studio 2015 - tsconfig.json - TypeScript 1.6.0 Beta

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

I created a blank `HTML application with TypeScript` using `File > New > Project` in VS2015.

I added a basic tsconfig.json in a `/scripts` folder and was expecting to have VS read the file and output the .js files into a different folder.  Unfortunately, nothing happens.  It's a though VS is not even finding the `tsconfig.json`

Is anyone else having this problem?

I am aware there was a previous problem with 1.5, but the previous fix doesn't seem to work:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4300

---------------- Update 9/10/2015

Here's one sample tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "amd",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "outDir": "../www/scripts/"
  },
  "files": [
    "./scripts/index.ts"
  ]
}
```

Here's another tsconfig.json

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "out": "/wwwroot/scripts/appBundle.js",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceRoot": "/"
    }
}
```

I have created tsconfig.json files for TypeScript + Cordova projects and they work correctly.

Comment: What does your tsconfig.json look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to typescript 1.8 Beta, .tsconfig was ignored for .net 4.x projects.  Now with this released, visual studio does recognize if there is a .tsconfig file and disables the other project types.

Just make sure you have uninstalled previous versions of Typescript for Visual Studio, and install the latest version.

Here is the install file for Typescript 1.8 Beta for VS: http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/D/8/6D8381B0-03C1-4BD2-AE65-30FF0A4C62DA/TS1.8.1-Beta-TS-master.20160126.1/TypeScript_Dev14Full.exe

Here is their announcement on it: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/01/28/announcing-typescript-1-8-beta/

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1. Try to place tsconfig.json file in root directory.

> By invoking tsc with no input files, in which case the compiler searches for the tsconfig.json file starting in the current directory and continuing up the parent directory chain.

Solution 2. As far as I know VS 2015 [can't work](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3983) with tsconfig files yet. I could make it work via build events.

Add in pre-build events "tsc" command. In your case if it's in script folder you have to pass --[project parameter](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Compiler-Options) `tsc --p scripts`. Otherwise you can use it without any parameter `tsc`.

[image]

**Note** tsc should be added to PATH.

How can this be done via [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/)

- Download and install [node](https://nodejs.org/en/)
- run command line
- execute `npm install -g typescript` to install [typescript package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript)

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I've been using `VS2015 + TypeScript + Cordova` for my projects and `tsconfig.json` is supported. I think it was supported since CTP6. It's so important to have this feature by default, but maybe I'm missing something with `HTML Application with TypeScript`  Here's a screen shot of a blank Cordova TypeScript project 
![](http://i.imgur.com/unI49RE.png)

Comment: @DeanB_Develop could you try to put tsconfig.json to root directory? tsc compiler looks at root directory by default and if it can't find config file, it goes to parent directory. So may be it can't see json file in scripts subdirectory

Comment: @DeanB_Develop any luck?

Comment: No luck with the `tsconfig.json`.  However, I'm now using a `TypeScript Cordova` project with `browsersync`. I use a `gulpfile.js` & `Task Runner Explorer` to run browsersync.

   gulp.task('browser.sync', function () {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./www/"
        }
    });
    // add browserSync.reload to the tasks array to make
    // all browsers reload after tasks are complete.
    gulp.watch("js/*.js", ['browser.sync.js-watch']);
});
gulp.task('browser.sync.js-watch', ['js'], browserSync.reload);