# compile typescript throws exception for using decorators

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, angular, asp.net-core

I use Visual Studio 2015 with TS 1.7.5 in an asp.net core project.

I have setup a beginner angular 2 5min. tutorial.

I get this exception when I try to compile my scripts folder:

Why does the warning lead to failed process?

[image]

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>'
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You tsconfig looks correct :

```
"experimentalDecorators": true,
```

I suspect you have *two* tsconfig.json files and one if them is not right.

Comment: No there is only ONE tsconfig.json file under scripts in my visual studio. Is it maybe that the tsconfig.json is not considered somehow by visual studio because that was once the case (read in google about it) maybe its not fixed yet???

Comment: found another voice see last answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32465760/visual-studio-2015-tsconfig-json-typescript-1-6-0-beta

Comment: Ok after installing TS 1.8.2 I got this guy error: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6468 HAHA... Still use Beta6 now do beta7 ng2 upadate, lets see what breaks then ;-)