# The empty content of ts file in browse

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

I had created a project in ASP.NET-Core. The project has been configured, that for folder `wwwroot` contains only local files like `*.html, *.css, *.js` and so on. Files with extension `*.ts` are in other folder names `scripts`. All looks like:

[image]

Settings for *tsconfig.json*:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "../wwwroot/appScripts/",
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"    
  ]
}
```

Everything is good compile. As you can see: the property *sourceMap* (in tsconfig.json) has value **true**, well at the end of each `*.js` (created by **.ts*) is added sourceMapping:
[image]

*app.js.map*:

```
{
  "version": 3,
  "file": "app.js",
  "sourceRoot": "",
  "sources": [
    "../../scripts/app.ts"
  ],
  "names": [
    "AppComponent",
    "AppComponent.constructor"
  ],
  "mappings": "(...)"
}
```

List of `sources` points for good file ts:

[image]

I stared the project in Chrome / Chrome Canary (with / without debug - the same effect). Then go to source (*F12 -> Sources*). I see that the files `script/app.ts` and `script/boot.ts` are empty:
[image]

When i try to open `script/app.ts` in IE11 i get the error:

```
Could not locate http://localhost:61272/appScripts/../../scripts/app.ts specified in source map http://localhost:61272/appScripts/app.js.map.
```

Maybe you know what's wrong? **I think that this issue create another problem: I can't debug..**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The thing is that a browser can not find source files referenced in map file.

The [sourceRoot](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) option can help you to specify sources folder.

I'm using "inlineSourceMap" and "inlineSources" options in debug mode to overcome "source paths hell".

#### Update 1

Sample minimal tsconfig.json file to generate inline source maps:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"    
  ]
}
```

You will get something like

```
//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjozLCJmaWxlIjoiYXBwLmpz...
```

in output ".js" files.

But be aware of ignore of tsconfig.json file by Visual Studio 2015 under some circumstances (e.g. [Visual Studio 2015 - tsconfig.json - TypeScript 1.6.0 Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32465760/visual-studio-2015-tsconfig-json-typescript-1-6-0-beta))

To make it just work via VS, I've added "tsc" on post-build step. To get files complied I build the project.

But for production I'd recommend you to use Grunt or Gulp build tasks, or Webpack.

Comment: Thank you for tip. Can you give me part of your options? I'm newbie

Comment: Both `"inlineSourceMap": true` and `"inlineSources": true` were needed to make it work

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Chrome and not serving original `.ts` files along with `.js` files, you can point Chrome to a folder there original source files are kept without modifying server's configuration.

1. Open Dev Tools and navigate to the *Sources* tab.
2. Ensure that the FS tree is expanded (click [image: expand] button in top left corner if not).
3. Right-click anywhere in the tree panel and select *Add folder to workspace*.
4. Select the folder where `.ts` sources are located.
5. A security confirmation bar will appear in the main viewport, accept it.

Answer (score 4):

The problem I see is that in your `wwwroot` directory you only have served up and deployed the `.js` and `.map` files. The problem is the other piece of the puzzle for the `.map` file is the `.ts` file itself.

I had this same problem with the blank `.ts` files being displayed. For debugging purposes, you should have either `tsconfig.json` or your task runner (i.e. `gulp.js`) copy out *not just* the transpiled `.js` files but also the `.ts` files. I wrote a blog post detailing the comprehensive steps required in an ASP.NET Core site to ensure this happens if you need a deeper explanation:

[Ensuring TypeScript Files Are Served to the Browser for Debugging Using ASP.NET Core](http://www.allenconway.net/2016/09/ensuring-typescript-files-are-served-to.html)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding `.ts` with `text/plain` as a MIME-type in IIS 10.

This is the relevant part of my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "outFile": "scripts/app.js",
    "sourceMap": true,
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

This also "worked", but did not play nicely with the minification:

```
"inlineSourceMap": true,
"inlineSources": true
```

I'd rather have the `.map` file as a separate file